# Why doesn't grep work on some file, but works on another (same content)

Tags: grep

I wrote this grep command:

```
grep -- "^[0-9a-zA-Z\.-]\+$" file.txt
```

To get all lines containing only numbers, letters and dashes (legal domains).

This is the result of diff on both files

```
1,3c1,3
< test.xcom
< hi-th6ere.co.k
< 54
---
> test.xcom
> hi-th6ere.co.k
> 54
```

I wrote a file with some domains to test and it works great!

But, when I download a file (with the same content!) from the web, and then run this command, grep doesn't return anything.

I've tried to set full permissions on this file, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: You need to provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: do a `diff` on the file you've downloaded and your original file.

Comment: Hi I've edited the diff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What makes you think the file content as the same as the one you've tested?
You can run 'diff filename1 filename2' to see if there are any differences between the two files.
It could be the the file you're downloading is in unicode format, so in a web browser it looks to be have the same content as the file you've tested, but the binary content of the file itself is different.

Comment: Hi, I'm the one the created the one from the web server :) I've edited my question and post the result of diff (they are the same)

Comment: You might want to take another look at the diff output you posted - diff is telling you that those 3 lines are different between the 2 files. Check the files for trailing white space (`sed 's/.*/<&>/' file`), control chars (`cat -v file`), etc. and run `dos2unix` or similar if one has control-Ms in it. Also, fix your grep command to `grep -E -- '^[[:alnum:].-]+$' file.txt`

Comment: Hi, You're right. One was created in Windows and one in Unix, but I thought grep ignores the ^M characters, good to know. THANKS.